# What's the function of "lo" in "lo que"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, clíticos

Examples:

> Lo que pasa es que el niño no fue a la escuela porque se fracturo el tobillo.
>
> Lo que quiere es una computadora para hacer sus tareas.
>
> Lo que dice es mentira.
>
> Lo que no entiendo es por qué no tiene hambre si no ha comido nada desde la mañana.

The pattern is "lo que (verb) es/son [que]".

- What's the function of "lo" in "lo que"?
- What is "lo" referring to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a **pronoun**, being used to refer to *actions, concepts and ideas*, never for *nouns*, which require the use of *"El que..."*. Check [this page](http://roble.pntic.mec.es/acid0002/index_archivos/Gramatica/pronombres_relativos.htm) for more examples.

Consider the sentence:

> Lo que necesitamos es más tiempo.

In English it would be "**What** we need is more time" (Translation might seem clumsy, but it's to allow you to understand); "what" refers to "time".

Answer (score 3):

"Lo que" indeed means "what", not in the interrogative sense, but in the sense of "that which..."

Consider the following examples:

> Lo que importa es... / What matters is...
>
> Lo que me molesta es que ... / What bothers me is that...
>
> ¿Oíste lo que dijo? / Did you hear what s/he said?
>
> Haz lo que quieras. / Do whatever you want.
>
> Pase lo que pase  /  Whatever happens ... happens.